# DropDownFor and bool? not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use MVC and have a property with bool?.
I want to use a dropdown box for this, so my Model has a List like this:

```
var YesOrNoTriState = new List<SelectListItem> {
new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "" },
new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = true.ToString() },
new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = false.ToString() }
};
```

My model is null, so it has no value but true will be selected...

Here is my Razor Code:

```
   @Html.DropDownListFor(
                            x => x.MoProVerglasung,
                            Model.MoProVerglasungDropDown,
                            new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Why not just use `EditorFor(x => x.MoProVerglasung)` which will generate a dropdownlist if the property is nullable `bool`.

Comment: And if the value of `null`, tnhe the first option will be selected (or do you mean you want the second option to be selected, in which case you need to set the value of `MoProVerglasung` to `true`)

Comment: change `var YesOrNoTriState` to `ViewBag.YesOrNoTriState` and your dropdown to : `@Html.DropDownList("YesOrNoTriState", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.YesOrNoTriState, "")` or if you want to use the model leave it as it is but the dropdown should refer to `@Html.DropDownList("YesOrNoTriState", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)Model.YesOrNoTriState, "")` ... Personally, I'm always using the `ViewBag` for dropdowns and such

Comment: any reasons for using `MoProVerglasung` and `MoProVerglasungDropDown`? I suppose the first is just a `string` variable while the second is the `string List<>`